# How to set master details page with option selected in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-pages

I am creating an application using the Master details page. In that, there is one thing that I missed out is that when I open an application than at that time the first item is not selected here.
I try with different solutions like make "Custom View Cell" and make a renderer for solving that but there is also the same issue is raised.

I also mention the image below.

[image: Issue phases in master page]
Is there any solution in regards to that?

Comment: Can you share an example what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @AnubhavRanjan Thanks for the reply. I added detailed issue in question please look into that and do needful.

Comment: [How can we select the default page on a MasterDetail project?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/149153/how-can-we-select-the-default-page-on-a-masterdetail-project) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complicated , you can do it totally in Forms project without custom renderer.

I list the steps to achieve what you want .

1. Give the Model property to indicate which one is selected and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged.

   ```
   public class MasterPageItem  : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private bool isSelected;
       public bool IsSelected {
           get {
               return isSelected;
           }
           set {
               if (value != this.isSelected)
               {
                   this.isSelected = value;
                   NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
           } 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Bind with the background color of parent view in ViewCell and convert bool value to color in Converter

   ```
               <ViewCell>
                   <Grid Padding="5,10" BackgroundColor="{Binding IsSelected , Converter={StaticResource BooltoColor}}">
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                       <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                   </Grid>
               </ViewCell>

   public class BooltoColorConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           Color color ;

           if(((bool)value) == true)
           {
               color = Color.Gray;
           }
           else
           {
               color = Color.Transparent;
           }

           return color;
       }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Set the item as selected and set other item disselected when you tap the listview item.

   ```
   private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (MasterPageItem i in list)
       {
           i.IsSelected = false;
       }

       MasterPageItem item = e.Item as MasterPageItem;
       if (item != null)
       {
           item.IsSelected = true;
           list.RemoveAt(e.ItemIndex);
           list.Insert(e.ItemIndex, item);
       }
   }
   ```

Check my testing image and sample link below

[image]

https://github.com/ColeXm/MasterDetailedSample/blob/master/Xamarin_Forms___MasterDetailPage.zip